# problem with ImGui when using glfw, opengl

Tags: c++, runtime-error, imgui

I'm trying to add it into a  glfw window but its giving me this error

[image]

this is the line dropping the error

```
ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_Init(GL_renderer);
```

this is my imgui folder

[image]

this is main.cpp (there are no other files other than the imgui folder)

```
#include "imgui/imgui.h"

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include "imgui/imgui_impl_glfw.h"
#include "imgui/imgui_impl_opengl3.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    GLFWwindow* window;

    if (!glfwInit()) {
        return -1;
    }

    window = glfwCreateWindow(850, 500, "test window", NULL, NULL);




    // Setup Dear ImGui context
    IMGUI_CHECKVERSION();
    ImGui::CreateContext();
    ImGuiIO& io = ImGui::GetIO(); (void)io;

    // Setup Dear ImGui style
    ImGui::StyleColorsDark();
    //ImGui::StyleColorsClassic();

    // Setup Platform/Renderer backends
    ImGui_ImplGlfw_InitForOpenGL(window, true);

    char* GL_renderer = (char*)glGetString(GL_RENDERER);
    ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_Init(GL_renderer);




    if (!window) {
        return -1;
        glfwTerminate();
    }

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_NewFrame();
        ImGui_ImplGlfw_NewFrame();
        ImGui::NewFrame();

        ImGui::Begin("hello world window");


        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
}
```

please help, I've been trying to fix this error for 6 hours now

Answer (score 1):

There should be an `ImGui::End()` at the end like in every provided example.

```
ImGui::Begin("hello world window");
...
ImGui::End();
```

**Edit** Have you compiled the implementation file as well? https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/blob/master/imgui_draw.cpp

Answer (score 0):

it was giving me a null pointer error, I assume because it being a wrong variable type or something.

anyway in the example file for glfw opengl 3 a method like this is used at the beginning of the main function where the window is initialized to get the opengl render version, AKA the parameter for the function that is causing the error

```
// Decide GL+GLSL versions
#if defined(IMGUI_IMPL_OPENGL_ES2)
    // GL ES 2.0 + GLSL 100
    const char* glsl_version = "#version 100";
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_OPENGL_ES_API);
#elif defined(__APPLE__)
    // GL 3.2 + GLSL 150
    const char* glsl_version = "#version 150";
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);  // 3.2+ only
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);            // Required on Mac
#else
    // GL 3.0 + GLSL 130
    const char* glsl_version = "#version 130";
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);
    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);  // 3.2+ only
    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);            // 3.0+ only
#endif
```